# Git push completion not working for branch (second argument)

Tags: bash, git, autocomplete, git-push, tab-completion

So I have downloaded the `git-completion.bash` from [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) as you can see from the following output:

```
$ ls ~ | grep git-completion
-rw-r--r--   1 waldyr  staff  64720 Jul 21 23:43 .git-completion.bash
```

I'm running macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6 and I downloaded bash-completion using homebrew as you can see from the following output:

```
$ brew info bash-completion
bash-completion: stable 1.3 (bottled)
Programmable completion for Bash 3.2
https://salsa.debian.org/debian/bash-completion
Conflicts with:
  bash-completion@2 (because Differing version of same formula)
/usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_3 (189 files, 608.2KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-07-18 at 11:25:01
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/bash-completion.rb
==> Caveats
Add the following line to your ~/.bash_profile:
  [ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion ] && . /usr/local/etc/bash_completion

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
```

My `.bash_profile` sources a file called `.bashrc` which sources both `bash-completion` and `git completion` with telling the :

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile 
. ~/.bashrc

$ cat ~/.bashrc
[ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion ] && . /usr/local/etc/bash_completion

if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  source ~/.git-completion.bash

  __git_complete gp _git_push
fi
alias gp='git push'
```

Whenever I type `gp` in the terminal and press tab asking for completion the script works perfectly:

```
$ gp <tab>
origin       production
```

And after my selection of a repository the completion doesn't work for the refspec:

When there's nothing after it keeps showing the repositories:

```
$ gp origin <tab>
origin       production
```

If there's at least one letter it (for example `m` from `master`), it looks for the files in the current directory

```
$ gp origin m<tab>
Makefile  Minafile
```

I know I can alias `git` in the `bashrc` to `g` and alias `git-push` in `gitconfig` to `p` making the command `g p` which the completion works perfectly but I find annoying having to type the space.

What am I missing to make the completion work for the second argument (refspec)? Is that a git bug?

[Here is the link for my dotfiles](https://github.com/waldyr/dotfiles) so you can check the whole files.